# scoping in node.js with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I understand the principles of asynchronous functions, but something is not clear to me: Scoping in asynchronous functions.

Example:

```
    var path = "/my/folder/to/public/data";
    http.createServer(function(request, response){
            /* some malicious code is executed, however */
            path = "/my/folder/to/private/data"
    });

    /* go on, go on, go on, wait here because of an synchronous function. */
    /* while code execution is here, the callback-function of the server is called. */

    fs.readFile(path+"myfile.txt", function(err, content){
            console.log(content);
    });
```

So, this is only an example. But how does it behave with the scopes/vars?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1117720 explains it quite well

Comment: Please [don't use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). The server ate it because we don't want it.